# downloading pdf or image from a server and displaying it in C

Tags: c, pdf, client, server

I am trying to download a pdf through GET in HTTP 1.1 by connecting to server and sending the request through send() and getting it through recv().

I tried a beginners method of trying to create and open a file, then save into it whatever I recieved in the recv() call and save the file by pdf extension. But it does'nt work like that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You must have the knowledge of followings:

## Sockets

The HTTP protocal is based on Sockets and thus you must know about sockets. Sockets would help you to identify that when the request of data recv starts and how many bytes you have still pending. There are other things also which would help you know the other protocols of Internet which are based on sockets.

## HTTP

Second thing you must know about http requests and have to make a distinction between the headers and document text. As such sending the requestion and recieving data is easy but from where the acutal document starts in the recieving data is the question of knowledge and other things. As in HTTP request you come to know about length of document, type of document and other important things.

## PDF

If you want to download the PDF File at lease you must know from where the PDF Documents start and ends. Unless you know that you would not able to identify the begining of document and ending of document.